# Load properties from mysql database using liquibase and use maven filters for replace in other properties files

Tags: mysql, maven, filter, properties, liquibase

I would like to load the properties from liquibase and use those properties keys and values in other properties as part of maven build with filtering

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"\>
\<modelVersion\>4.0.0\</modelVersion\>

    <groupId>com.laxman.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-project</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>web-project Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>`your text`
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    
    
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.15.0</version>
                <configuration>
    
                    <changeLogFile>
                        src/main/resources/changelog-master.xml
                    </changeLogFile>
    
                    <propertyFile>
                        src/main/resources/liquibase.properties
                    </propertyFile>
    
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>8.0.33</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
 xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.12.xsd">


 <changeSet id="export-data-to-file" author="your_name">
  <!-- Execute a custom SQL script to export data to a file -->
  <sqlFile path="sql/export-data.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
 </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>

Comment: The above one is for change log file details I forgot to mention

Comment: Add additional information to your question using the edit function, not as comment.